# How Enthalpy sensor work - practically?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, sensor

There are many links to enthalpy sensors used in industry, but have not found anything on the principle of their work. For example, thermometer mechanism could be a liquid (mercury) expanding predictably at certain temperature, or thermistor changing electrical resistance depending on the temperature. No similar explanation I found for the sensor of enthalpy.

Example of unit: 
https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/Techlit/TechLitDocuments/63-0000s/63-2724.pdf

Basically my questions are:

- What sensor(s) are inside this and similar units ? (I see they mention thermistor, but this is apparently not the only thing)
- How this can be translated into enthalpy measure (energy units) ?
- What practical conclusions can I make from knowing enthalpy ?

Comment: I don't think there's any such thing as an enthalpy sensor. Enthalpy is a quantity that is calculated rather than measured directly.

Comment: Would you please give an example of the device you mention, such that we could have a chance to understand your question ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many links to devices themselves, for example https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/Techlit/TechLitDocuments/63-0000s/63-2724.pdfhttps://customer.honeywell.com/resources/Techlit/TechLitDocuments/63-0000s/63-2724.pdf , but have not found anything on the principle. Most of applications I see are in HVAC (air related Heating, Ventilation, Air Conditioning) but there are also water heating applications. Also I saw some mentions of chemistry lab applications. I am more interested in industrial aspect. Thank you.

Comment: An "enthalpy sensor" measures both temperature and humidity and then calculates enthalpy; it assumes water vapor in air.  See  http://www.industrialcontrolsonline.com/training/online/enthalpy for a pretty thorough explanation.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Electrical engineering deals with sensors for sure, but enthalpy is not electrical parameter. Also, one can measure some similar parameter by non-electric methods at all (e.g. temperature by thermometer).

Comment: Thanks Mark, indeed this explains one particular case of a system, method specific for that system and one particular use. I was wondering if there are more generic methods which would work in a wider variety of systems and give more general explanation

Comment: Not sure what is unclear with this question. I clarified: gave example of a device for specific use, and asked for more general methods to allow one to measure enthalpy in other systems, and/or generic method suitable for all. It is perfectly possible that there is no answer, but the question is quite specific. @JohnRennie - I did bring to your attention specific enthalphy sensor.